# Purple/Pink lines on screen after login on Ubuntu Desktop 13.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, login, visual-artifacts

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 and I loaded up the live system. It loaded up fine but when I clicked on the Ubuntu logo purple and pink lines appeared on screen and they didn't go away so I thought that if I installed the OS it would be fine so I installed the OS, logged in and lo and behold the purple and pink lines where back.

My video card is nVidia N force (I think)
Anyone having the same problem???

Answer (score 0):

I've seen purple and pink geometric artifacts on the Ubuntu desktop before. I discovered that the problem was due to a failing graphics card. Swapping the graphics card with another graphics card solved the problem. Generalizing from this experience, I recommend that you install the correct graphics drivers for your system with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove
sudo ubuntu-drivers install 
sudo reboot
```

If that doesn't work look for a way to temporarily swap your graphics card with another one for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics driver issues can cause the artifacts you describe.
If this is a fresh install, I'd recommend running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(to update the OS, including its drivers) and then going to Additional Drivers at the start menu, and see what Ubuntu offers.

Now, to be completely honest, at my office we have 4 GeForce6100 cards (nForce chipset) and NONE of them works properly with any driver in Ubuntu 12.04. Using 3D mode causes random crashes that require logout/reboot, while 2D mode works OK.

We chose to stick to 2D using the current Nvidia drivers (via `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` and then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x-swat && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Update your Nvidia driver.  To do so, open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then reboot.